# How can I get VBA to copy formulas into a calculated range on every worksheet that matches a pattern?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate the following problem: I have an excel workbook with a large number of quotes (each quote tab is in the format of "Q-#####"). Each quote tab has a series of calculations. I updated cell "L6" on every tab. Starting on row 6, there are a number of SKUs - each quote tab has a different number of SKUs.

The below is trying to do the following:

1. Determine if the worksheet starts with "Q-"
2. Determine the row of the last SKU (None go past row 100 so I put that to hopefully save time) then I remove 5 because I want to count the number of rows past L6
3. I want to then set the range as L6 to the last row by using the integer I determined in step 2
4. Then I want to copy the formula in L6 and paste it into every cell in my range (it's a very long formula that uses relative references so I wanted paste formulas)

I fixed my previous error (thanks BigBen) and now the copy/paste function is only working on the first identified Q- tab. On the subsequent Q tabs, I can see it selecting the right ranges but the paste doesn't work.

Accountant here, so I'm trying my best but a complete novice!

````
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Q-*" Then
        Dim nRows As Integer
        nRows = ws.Range("L6:L100").Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        nRows = nRows - 5

        Range("L6").Copy

        Dim cell As Range
        Set cell = Range("L6")
        cell.Resize(nRows, 1).Select

        cell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormulas)

    End If

Next ws

End Sub```
````

Comment: The problem is `nRows = lastRow - 5`... you used `lastRow` instead of `nRows`. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and it will flag undeclared variables, like `lastRow`.

Comment: Oh shoot, thank you! I have been fiddling back and forth for an hour and missed it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Highly recommend you go to *Tools* > *Options* and click *Require Variable Declaration.* It will add `Option Explicit` for you automatically going forward.

Comment: For some reason when I run the program, the copy/paste aspect only works on the first Q tab that is identified. On the subsequently found tabs, I can see it working (i.e., calculating and selecting the correct range), but the formula does not paste anything. I'm stuck on why the copy/paste does not work because I am doing the copy within the loop.

Comment: That's because you need to qualify the `Worksheet` that the `Range`s are on... and simplifying a bit, `ws.Range("L6").Copy`, then `ws.Range("L6").Resize(nRows).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas`. `Dim cell`, `Set cell`, `.Select`ing... you can drop all that.

Comment: If you don't qualify the worksheet, then there's an implicit `ActiveSheet`.